# easier way to code series of images javascript

Tags: javascript

In the code below, I've successfully made it so when someone clicks on a thumbnail of a picture, it's full picture will come up in the target.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a nicer way to create onclick events for multiple thumbnails I would like to make this expandable.

Also, please consider only javaScript answers as I don't write in jQuery (yet!).

```js
var img = document.getElementById("galleryImg");
var thumb = document.getElementsByClassName("imgThumb");
var p0 = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89495286/test/images/pic1.png";
var p1 = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89495286/test/images/pic2.png";
var p2 = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89495286/test/images/pic3.png";
var p3 = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89495286/test/images/pic4.png";
var p4 = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89495286/test/images/pic5.png";
var p5 = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89495286/test/images/pic6.png";

var pArray = [p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]

img.src = pArray[0];

thumb[0].onclick = function(){pic0()};
function pic0(){img.src = pArray[0]};

thumb[1].onclick = function(){pic1()};
function pic1(){img.src = pArray[1]};

thumb[2].onclick = function(){pic2()};
function pic2(){img.src = pArray[2]};

thumb[3].onclick = function(){pic3()};
function pic3(){img.src = pArray[3]};

thumb[4].onclick = function(){pic4()};
function pic4(){img.src = pArray[4]};

thumb[5].onclick = function(){pic5()};
function pic5(){img.src = pArray[5]};
```

Comment: Have you learned about arrays yet?

Comment: Absolutely.  I wanted to know if there were a better way to call items from an Array and attach an onclick function to them.  That way I can theoretically add any amount of thumbnails (or any other item).

Comment: Arrays go hand-in-hand with loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you'll have the same amount of elements in `pArray` as you would have thumbnails, you would do this:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(thumb, function(thumbItem, index) {
  thumbItem.onclick = function() {
    img.src = pArray[index];
  };
});
```

It iterates through the thumbnails, attaching the `onclick` handler and assigning the main image with the corresponding image based on the element's index.

Comment: Yes, I was about to post something like this, except that I would suggest `[].forEach.call` instead of `Array.prototype.forEach` =P

Comment: Yeah, that is doable, but I prefer the explicitness :).

Comment: Since `pArray` is an array, you could use it as the basis for the `forEach`

Comment: Thanks!  Works perfectly.  I will research this new code and see why it works.

Answer (score 0):

You iterate over the array, however, using a loop alone will not completely fix the problem, because you're assigning a function inside the loop, which means any outside variables could change before the `onclick` executes.

So what you need is a closure.

1. Create a function that sets the `onclick` callback
2. Call that function in a loop.

Here's an example:

```
function setOnClick(element, imgSrc) {
  element.onclick = function() { img.src = imgSrc; };
}

for (var i = 0; i < thumb.length; i++) {
  setOnClick(thumb[i], pArray[i]);
}
```

This functionality is very common, so it has also been implemented by [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
pArray.forEach(function(imgSrc, index) {
  thumb[index].onclick = function() { img.src = imgSrc; };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `loop` for any array, we usually use the `for loop` for related arrays.

```
for (var i = 0; i < thumb.length; i++) {
    thumb[i].src = pArray[i]; // change if different src
    thumb[i].onclick = function() { img.src = this.src; };
}
```

Try on: https://jsfiddle.net/Zay_DEV/8r1gqnfx/

```js
var img = document.getElementById("galleryImg");
var thumb = document.getElementsByClassName("imgThumb");
var pArray = [
 "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89495286/test/images/pic1.png",
  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89495286/test/images/pic2.png",
  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89495286/test/images/pic3.png",
  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89495286/test/images/pic4.png",
  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89495286/test/images/pic5.png",
  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89495286/test/images/pic6.png"
]

for (var i = 0; i < thumb.length; i++) {
 thumb[i].src = pArray[i];
 thumb[i].onclick = function() { img.src = this.src; };
}

thumb[0].onclick();
```

```css
#galleryImg { max-height: 25vh; }
.imgThumb { width: 100px; height: 50px; }
```

```html
<img id="galleryImg"/>
<br />

<img class="imgThumb"/>
<img class="imgThumb"/>
<img class="imgThumb"/>
<img class="imgThumb"/>
<img class="imgThumb"/>
<img class="imgThumb"/>
```

Comment: I don't think `thumb` is supposed to have that `src`. If it's a thumbnail, it probably has a different image file. Very good use of `this` though.

Comment: I agree.  However, it is a great idea if you don't mind using a smaller version of the original image.  And it would skip having to create smaller thumbnails thereby leading to less upload bandwidth.  I'll have to consider this one.